# Do I have to change my image location to find it?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I'm trying to find an image in my JSF project. Here's my folder structure:

[image]

The image is inside the "imagesFedex" folder.

I'm trying to find its path like this:

```
String ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();

try {
    FileInputStream imagem = new FileInputStream(ctx + "/src/main/webapp/imagesFedex/nova_logorapidao2.png");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it's throwing the filenotfound exception. I've read that the images goes inside the resources folder. Do I have to change its location? How can I get this path correctly?

Comment: To debug this problem, you should check the value of `ctx`.

Comment: @RobinKrahl the value of ctx is "/solis_web"

Comment: You should know that the folder structure of your project in your IDE, is not the same as what's unbundled into the deployment folder of your application server. You should have a dedicated folder (that is *not* within your source tree) that holds assets and resources like images